# Handler.PostDelayed(runnable, time) doesn't stop

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my code i need to call some functions every 5 seconds (for example) and when i press again the button i need to suspend the runnable but doesn't work because in the log i keep reading that the runnable still call again the methods.

```
   //Listner for button that search location for travel
    startMonit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable runnable = null;


            if (startMonit.getText().toString().equals("MONITORIZZA")) {

                Log.i(TAG,"dentro equals Monitorizza");
                startMonit.setText("STOP");
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "run Handler post delayed");
                        getUserLocation(true); //true because i have travel coordinates and i need to monitorate travel distance
                        //getDistanceTime(travelInfo);

                        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000); //now is every 2 minutes
                    }
                };

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000); //Every 120000 ms (2 minutes)

            }else {
                Log.i(TAG,"dentro equals non monitorizza");
                startMonit.setText("MONITORIZZA");
                //Rimuovo il thread che monitorizza
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
            }

        }

    });
```

Where i'm wrong with this code?

Comment: do you see the else part executed? every time you click the button you have instantiate a new Handler

Comment: oh my Godness....you are very right!
Too many time over this code and i don't see this stupid (mine) error.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Better if you use a Timer and TimerTask

Comment: Why is better the Timer?

Comment: Have you tried this: handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

Comment: @Hammad the problem was that i create a new instance of Handler every click so i can't close the last one :D